# can't write " sign instantly, have to tap twice

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I always have to type 2 times on **"** in order for it appear, and it "" already, but not instantly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keyboard is set to "US International" and so <kbd>"</kbd> is acting as a [**dead key**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) so that you can enter things such as "ë" via <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. Changing it back to "US" will remove this behavior.